# validate several JSONs with a single JSONSchema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to know if it is possible to use a single JSONSchema (draft-04) to validate several JSONs, for example:

JSON 1:

```
{   
  "Credentiales": {   
    "Name": "123456",   
    "Password": "word"
  },
  "Reference": "1"
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
    "ConsumerInfo": {
        "Reference": "1",
        "Consumer": "89",
        "FirstName": "Ern",
        "LastName": "Torres",
        "Address": "White Street 50",
        "City": "Ges",
        "State": "Santa",
        "PhoneNumber": "+12354569874",
        "ConfirmedEmailingDate": "2017-02-15 03:10:55"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Welcome! You can use the same JSON Schema file to validate as many JSON instances as you want. I'm not really sure what you are asking here. Can you give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do and maybe some code please?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Is that I need to validate several JSON (REST service) of different operations and I want to do it with a single file Json Schema, that's my idea.

Comment: OK. What schema do you have so far? Have you created a schema for each of your examples and you want to combine them? If so, please provide those two schemas.

Comment: What is the reason you want to only use one JSON Schema? Usually you create one per JSON response type you want to validate. Looking at your examples, you have VERY different data models, which is quite normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The idea is to use `oneOf` keyword and `$ref` to reuse definitions. This JSON schema validates one or the other (I didn't specify all CustomerInfo properties, but you get the idea, so please fill in the blanks)

--EDIT 2018-09-01--

Draft-04 JSON schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "JSON schema of Credentiales and CustomerInfo",
    "definitions": {
        "Credentiales": {
            "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                "Name": {"type": "string"},
                "Password": {"type": "string"}
            }
        },
        "Reference": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Reference": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Reference"},
                "Consumer": {"type": "string"},
                "FirstName": {"type": "string"}
                !!!! FILL IN THE BLANKS: ADD THE OTHER PROPERTIES HERE AND REMOVE THIS COMMENT !!!
            },
            "additionalProperties": {"not": {}}
        }
    },

    "oneOf": [
          {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
               "Credentiales": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Credentiales"
                },
               "Reference": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Reference"
                },
               "additionalProperties": {"not": {}}
           }
          },
          {"$ref":"#/definitions/CustomerInfo"}
        ]
}
```

--EDIT 2018-08-31--

Draft-06 JSON schema version:

```
{  
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
    "title": "JSON schema of Credentiales and CustomerInfo",
    "definitions": {
        "Credentiales": {
            "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                "Name": {"type": "string"},
                                "Password": {"type": "string"}
            }
        },
        "Reference": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Reference": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Reference"},
                "Consumer": {"type": "string"},
                "FirstName": {"type": "string"}
              !!!! FILL IN THE BLANKS: ADD THE OTHER PROPERTIES HERE AND REMOVE THIS COMMENT !!!
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },

    "oneOf": [
          {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
               "Credentiales": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Credentiales"
                },
               "Reference": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Reference"
                },
               "additionalProperties": false
           }
          },
          {"$ref":"#/definitions/CustomerInfo"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really worked for me, that's what I wanted. Although I have other doubts:
1. that file is with the definition of draft-06, is there any problem with using the definition draft-04?
2. one could use more restrictions in the document, for example so that in a JSON file only the elements mentioned in the schema can be used (as well as in an XSD that the obligatory and optional elements are defined, and no more can be added in the xml file to be analyzed).

Thank you very much.

Comment: I added a version compatible with draft-04. **If this answer is OK for you, you may vote up and accept the answer.** For draft-04 compatibility, the main difference is `additionalProperties: false` replaced with `additionalProperties: {"not": {}}`. Check the [draft06 release notes](http://json-schema.org/draft-06/json-schema-release-notes.html#q-what-are-the-changes-between-draft-04-and-draft-06) for changes from draft04. As for restrictions, `additionalProperties: false` means that you cannot have other properties than the ones mentioned in the schema.

Comment: You may also use `required` keyword to make some properties mandatory.